# Apache zeppelin unable to fetch URL from Amazon S3 notebook json file

Tags: apache, amazon-s3, import, apache-zeppelin

Hi I am unable to import a notebook from amazon S3 after following tutorials and instructions on AWS site. Specifically, 
1. I have a notebook created by Zeppelin in S3, 
2. I have spun up a cluster with Zepplin, Spark, etc. installed
3. I provided a JSON configuration file on creating the EC2 clusters so that Zeppelin would save files to my S3 bucket:

[
  {
    "Classification": "zeppelin-env",
    "Properties": {

```
},
"Configurations": [
  {
    "Classification": "export",
    "Properties": {
    "ZEPPELIN_NOTEBOOK_STORAGE":"org.apache.zeppelin.notebook.repo.S3NotebookRepo",
      "ZEPPELIN_NOTEBOOK_S3_BUCKET":"bucket-name",
      "ZEPPELIN_NOTEBOOK_USER":"user-name"
    },
    "Configurations": [

    ]
  }
]
```

}
]

4. When I try to import a note on Zeppelin using the note URL provided by Amazon I get the error "Unable to fetch URL".

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want just to import a note from your S3 account into Zeppelin, you could use simply import menu of Zeppelin with the public url of your note in S3. In this case I believe you don't need to set all the configurations you did.

However, in case if you want to use S3 as a storage layer for Zeppelin, so that you can read and write into your S3 accout, you can use [this documentation](https://zeppelin.apache.org/docs/0.7.0/storage/storage.html#notebook-storage-in-s3). This is similar to the configuration you were trying to setup, however it should be done under `conf/zeppelin-env.sh` and `conf/zeppelin-site.xml` files, as documenatation says. If you were trying to achieve this option, then you don't need import menu and when Zeppelin starts, it will use `s3://bucket-name/user-name` as default notebook storage path, and all your note manipulaitons will be saved there.